Could not load file or assembly ‘Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions, Version=6.35.0.0. Nuget version mismatch Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions
I am developing a C# dll based on .NET framework 4.8.2 which will use Microsoft Graph API to send email through outlook.
For this I have added the latest Nuget packages for “Microsoft.Graph” v5.67.0 and "Microsoft.Identity.Client" v4.66.2 . This is my csproj -
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph">
      <Version>5.67.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Client">
      <Version>4.66.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility">
      <Version>9.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
      <Version>13.0.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Std.UriTemplate" Version="2.0.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CSharp">
      <Version>4.7.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

The build is successfull but I am getting this runtime error -
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly ‘Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions, Version=6.35.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35’ or one of its dependencies. The located assembly’s manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: ‘Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions, Version=6.35.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35’
Now, “Microsoft.Graph” v5.67.0 is dependent upon latest 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions, Version=8.2.0.0 but I am not able to figure out which module is dependent upon 6.35.0.0.
**Upon further looking, it is found out that, in obj/project.asset.json file there is a mismatch between 'Microsoft.IdentityModel components. “Microsoft.Graph.Core/3.2.1” is referring to “Microsoft.IdentityModel.Validators”: “8.2.0” but "Microsoft.Identity.Client/4.66.2"is referring to old 6.35.0 version.
**
Here is the obj/project.asset.json file -
"Microsoft.Graph/5.67.0": {
        "type": "package",
        "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.Graph.Core": "3.2.1"
        },

"Microsoft.Graph.Core/3.2.1": {
        "type": "package",
        "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect": "8.2.0",
          "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Validators": "8.2.0",
          "Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions": "1.15.2",
          "Microsoft.Kiota.Authentication.Azure": "1.15.2",
          "Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary": "1.15.2",
          "Microsoft.Kiota.Serialization.Form": "1.14.0",
          "Microsoft.Kiota.Serialization.Json": "1.15.2",
          "Microsoft.Kiota.Serialization.Multipart": "1.14.0",
          "Microsoft.Kiota.Serialization.Text": "1.14.0",
          "System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler": "6.0.0"
        },

"Microsoft.Identity.Client/4.66.2": {
        "type": "package",
        "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions": "6.35.0",
          "System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource": "6.0.1"
        },

In Microsoft.Identity.Client/4.66.2 release note it is mentioned that it will work with “Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions” >= 6.35.0 but in reality it is not.
Please advise me how to fix this error
In Microsoft.Identity.Client/4.66.2 release note it is mentioned that it will work with “Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions” >= 6.35.0 but in reality it is not.
I am providing the csproj and config files.
app.config -
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Memory" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.2" newVersion="4.0.1.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.2.0.0" newVersion="8.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.1" newVersion="6.0.0.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.15.2.0" newVersion="1.15.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Text.Json" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.5" newVersion="8.0.0.5" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Text.Encodings.Web" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Memory.Data" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Buffers" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>

packages.config -
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Azure.Core" version="1.44.1" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" version="8.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.TimeProvider" version="8.0.1" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Graph" version="5.67.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Graph.Core" version="3.2.1" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Identity.Client" version="4.66.2" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions" version="8.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens" version="8.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging" version="8.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols" version="8.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect" version="8.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" version="8.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Validators" version="8.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions" version="1.15.2" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Kiota.Authentication.Azure" version="1.15.2" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary" version="1.15.2" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Kiota.Serialization.Form" version="1.14.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Kiota.Serialization.Json" version="1.15.2" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Kiota.Serialization.Multipart" version="1.14.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Kiota.Serialization.Text" version="1.14.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Std.UriTemplate" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Buffers" version="4.5.1" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.ClientModel" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" version="6.0.1" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" version="8.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Memory" version="4.5.5" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Memory.Data" version="6.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler" version="6.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Numerics.Vectors" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="6.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encodings.Web" version="8.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Text.Json" version="8.0.5" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" version="4.5.4" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.ValueTuple" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net48" />
</packages>

csproj file -
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{94F3FFBE-B36A-43AE-813D-6F8AD4570654}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>MicrosoftGraphAPIApp</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>MicrosoftGraphAPIApp</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
    <FileUpgradeFlags>
    </FileUpgradeFlags>
    <OldToolsVersion>2.0</OldToolsVersion>
    <UpgradeBackupLocation />
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
    <PublishUrl>publish\</PublishUrl>
    <Install>true</Install>
    <InstallFrom>Disk</InstallFrom>
    <UpdateEnabled>false</UpdateEnabled>
    <UpdateMode>Foreground</UpdateMode>
    <UpdateInterval>7</UpdateInterval>
    <UpdateIntervalUnits>Days</UpdateIntervalUnits>
    <UpdatePeriodically>false</UpdatePeriodically>
    <UpdateRequired>false</UpdateRequired>
    <MapFileExtensions>true</MapFileExtensions>
    <ApplicationRevision>0</ApplicationRevision>
    <ApplicationVersion>1.0.0.%2a</ApplicationVersion>
    <IsWebBootstrapper>false</IsWebBootstrapper>
    <UseApplicationTrust>false</UseApplicationTrust>
    <BootstrapperEnabled>true</BootstrapperEnabled>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    </NuGetPackageImportStamp>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>..\..\..\..\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <NoWarn>1607</NoWarn>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>AllRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>..\..\..\..\Release</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <NoWarn>1607</NoWarn>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>AllRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SignAssembly>true</SignAssembly>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>..\..\..\Include\IRIS.snk</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Azure.Core, Version=1.44.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>C:\IPS\v25.1\Source\packages\Azure.Core.1.44.1\lib\net472\Azure.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>C:\IPS\v25.1\Source\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.8.0.0\lib\net462\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Bcl.TimeProvider, Version=8.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>C:\IPS\v25.1\Source\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.TimeProvider.8.0.1\lib\net462\Microsoft.Bcl.TimeProvider.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Graph, Version=5.67.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>C:\IPS\v25.1\Source\packages\Microsoft.Graph.5.67.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Graph.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Graph.Core, Version=3.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>C:\IPS\v25.1\Source\packages\Microsoft.Graph.Core.3.2.1\lib\net462\Microsoft.Graph.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Client, Version=4.66.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0a613f4dd989e8ae, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>C:\IPS\v25.1\Source\packages\Microsoft.Identity.Client.4.66.2\lib\net472\Microsoft.Identity.Client.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions, Version=8.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>C:\IPS\v25.1\Source\packages\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions.8.2.0\lib\net472\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens, Version=8.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>C:\IPS\v25.1\Source\packages\Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.8.2.0\lib\net472\Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging, Version=8.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>C:\IPS\v25.1\Source\packages\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.8.2.0\lib\net472\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols, Version=8.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>C:\IPS\v25.1\Source\packages\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.8.2.0\lib\net472\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect, Version=8.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>C:\IPS\v25.1\Source\packages\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.8.2.0\lib\net472\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens, Version=8.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>C:\IPS\v25.1\Source\packages\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.8.2.0\lib\net472\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Validators, Version=8.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>C:\IPS\v25.1\Source\packages\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Validators.8.2.0\lib\net472\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Validators.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions, Version=1.15.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>C:\IPS\v25.1\Source\packages\Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions.1.15.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Kiota.Authentication.Azure, Version=1.15.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>C:\IPS\v25.1\Source\packages\Microsoft.Kiota.Authentication.Azure.1.15.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Kiota.Authentication.Azure.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary, Version=1.15.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>C:\IPS\v25.1\Source\packages\Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary.1.15.2\lib\net462\Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Kiota.Serialization.Form, Version=1.14.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>C:\IPS\v25.1\Source\packages\Microsoft.Kiota.Serialization.Form.1.14.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Kiota.Serialization.Form.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Kiota.Serialization.Json, Version=1.15.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>C:\IPS\v25.1\Source\packages\Microsoft.Kiota.Serialization.Json.1.15.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Kiota.Serialization.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Kiota.Serialization.Multipart, Version=1.14.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>C:\IPS\v25.1\Source\packages\Microsoft.Kiota.Serialization.Multipart.1.14.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Kiota.Serialization.Multipart.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Kiota.Serialization.Text, Version=1.14.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>C:\IPS\v25.1\Source\packages\Microsoft.Kiota.Serialization.Text.1.14.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Kiota.Serialization.Text.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
    <Reference Include="Std.UriTemplate, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c118b0afb4598f9a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>C:\IPS\v25.1\Source\packages\Std.UriTemplate.2.0.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Std.UriTemplate.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Buffers, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>C:\IPS\v25.1\Source\packages\System.Buffers.4.5.1\lib\net461\System.Buffers.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.ClientModel, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>C:\IPS\v25.1\Source\packages\System.ClientModel.1.1.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.ClientModel.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=6.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>C:\IPS\v25.1\Source\packages\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.6.0.1\lib\net461\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.IdentityModel" />
    <Reference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, Version=8.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>C:\IPS\v25.1\Source\packages\System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.8.2.0\lib\net472\System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>C:\IPS\v25.1\Source\packages\System.Memory.4.5.5\lib\net461\System.Memory.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Memory.Data, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>C:\IPS\v25.1\Source\packages\System.Memory.Data.6.0.0\lib\net461\System.Memory.Data.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>C:\IPS\v25.1\Source\packages\System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.6.0.0\lib\net461\System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics" />
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>C:\IPS\v25.1\Source\packages\System.Numerics.Vectors.4.5.0\lib\net46\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>C:\IPS\v25.1\Source\packages\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.6.0.0\lib\net461\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Text.Encodings.Web, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>C:\IPS\v25.1\Source\packages\System.Text.Encodings.Web.8.0.0\lib\net462\System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Text.Json, Version=8.0.0.5, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>C:\IPS\v25.1\Source\packages\System.Text.Json.8.0.5\lib\net462\System.Text.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>C:\IPS\v25.1\Source\packages\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.4.5.4\lib\net461\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>C:\IPS\v25.1\Source\packages\System.ValueTuple.4.5.0\lib\net47\System.ValueTuple.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="IsolMicrosoftGraphAPIApp.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="..\..\..\Include\IRIS.snk">
      <Link>IRIS.snk</Link>
    </None>
    <None Include="app.config" />
    <None Include="packages.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>

Please advise me how to fix this error

We need a minimal repro if you want useful help. It looks like you're using a non-SDK styled project which I wouldn't recommend even if you are building for .NETFramework. Are you building a library that references those two NuGets and seeing this error in a Application that uses the library OR are you just testing with a console project that uses the NuGet packages? I did the former and could not repro; the appropriate bindingRedirects were generated by the build system.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Follow this instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/how-to-enable-and-disable-automatic-binding-redirection#enable-automatic-binding-redirects-manually and rebuild the solution

@Hank,
I did not get any error using the nugets in a similar standalone program. But when I added the standalone program in my organization module, this errors popped up.
I have given complete app.config, packages.config and csproj files for reference

For this issue, i have some suggestions to troubleshoot:
Method 1-Uninstall and Reinstall:
1.Run  the following two commands in the Package Console
uninstall-package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions -Force

install-package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions -Version "6.35.0"

Note: -Force :Forces a package to be uninstalled, even if other packages depend on it.
Method2- Modify your app.congig or web.config file
1.Check what is the version of your Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions actually referenced by Microsoft.Identity.Client/4.66.2 . You can run the following commands to check the source of a transitive package.
Installation: dotnet tool install --global dotnet-depends
Usage: dotnet depends .\MyProject.csproj


2. Add dependent assembly to your config file.
For example:
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions"  publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.35.0.0" newVersion="8.2.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>


Thanks for your reply @Dou Xu-MSFT.

for the first option, the Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions -Force was successfully uninstalled but could not install 6.35.0 as several other dependencies were of 8.2.0.0. So, the installation failed.
The package dependency is exactly as you have shown. But after changing the config file, the result is still the same.

I have updated my main question with app.config, packages.config and csproj. Can you please have a look.

Copy all your three files above to my local and build the project, no getting runtime error. Suggestions: 1.Clean build and obj file 2. Check if old version exists and clean old versions installed at C:\Users\USERNAME.nuget\packages.
